# Use a function to loop through rows, prior row is the input for the next row

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=10:1)
```

I have a following function:

```
fun <- function(x,y) x*y/1000+x+y
```

I want the following output:

```
 for (i in 2:10){df$a[i] = fun(df$a[i],df$a[i-1])};for (i in 2:10){df$b[i] = fun(df$b[i],df$b[i-1])}}

df
#            a        b
# 1   1.000000 10.00000
# 2   3.002000 19.09000
# 3   6.011006 27.24272
# 4  10.035050 34.43342
# 5  15.085225 40.64002
# 6  21.175737 45.84322
# 7  28.323967 50.02659
# 8  36.550559 53.17667
# 9  45.879514 55.28303
# 10 56.338309 56.33831
```

Essentially, the element for row i is the function output from the last row and current row, and this is executed recursively. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I think your for-loop code should be like this `for (i in 2:10){df$a[i] = fun(df$a[i],df$a[i-1])}; for (i in 2:10){df$b[i] = fun(df$b[i],df$b[i-1])}
`. You missed one `}` before the `;` sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the `accumulate` function from the `purrr` package.

```
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=10:1)

fun <- function(x,y) x*y/1000+x+y

df$a <- accumulate(df$a, fun)
df$b <- accumulate(df$b, fun)

df
#            a        b
# 1   1.000000 10.00000
# 2   3.002000 19.09000
# 3   6.011006 27.24272
# 4  10.035050 34.43342
# 5  15.085225 40.64002
# 6  21.175737 45.84322
# 7  28.323967 50.02659
# 8  36.550559 53.17667
# 9  45.879514 55.28303
# 10 56.338309 56.33831
```

Answer (score 2):

A `base R` option is with `Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE`

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) Reduce(fun, x, accumulate = TRUE))
df
#           a        b
#1   1.000000 10.00000
#2   3.002000 19.09000
#3   6.011006 27.24272
#4  10.035050 34.43342
#5  15.085225 40.64002
#6  21.175737 45.84322
#7  28.323967 50.02659
#8  36.550559 53.17667
#9  45.879514 55.28303
#10 56.338309 56.33831
```